# Global Proxy - Tunnel All Traffic to Proxy

Tags: network

How do i make OSX go through a proxy server for all the applications that use internet?

The system preferences proxy network setting only routes depending if the application supports it, but an ideal solution would be a way to tunnel everything to a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question has been asked and answered over at Superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/802967/how-can-i-make-sure-all-my-macs-tcp-traffic-goes-through-a-socks5-proxy

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line or link.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions